# fatfree framework cant route post with token

Tags: php, url-routing, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to setup a route similar to the following but it keeps giving me 405 Error

```js
$f3->route('POST /brew/@count',
    function($f3) {
        echo $f3->get('PARAMS.count').' bottles of beer on the wall.';
    }
);
```

I'm not interested on the @count because the values are being POST, it's just how the route is being generated and posted with a different @count.
I only need the routing feature of this framework.

Comment: did you fix your problem already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must define GET route instead of POST if you need to access in browser without POST data too. Here is the example.

```
$f3->route('GET|POST /brew/@count',
    function($f3) {
        echo $f3->get('PARAMS.count').' bottles of beer on the wall.';
    }
);
```